# Should punctuation always match the text format in HTML?

Tags: html, typography

I am asking this out curiosity. I want to know if there's a rule or standard to include punctuation along with the text format, such as in the following:

```
<i>This is italic</i>; but a semicolon exists outside of it.
```

or

`<b>This sentence is in a bold format</b>. The period is not included inside it though.`

Does it matter that the punctuation exists outside of its format or not, if so on what standard it based upon?

Comment: I assume there is no rule in this case.

Comment: Specially in the second example it would only make sense to me to include the period in the bold tag. But broader speaking, different languages usually have different rules on punctuation in different contexts. Apart from different quote characters, in French you'd leave a space before a period, exclamation- or question mark. When it comes to quoting inside a sentence, in (US) English you would include the punctuation character inside the quotes, _"This is," he exclaimed [...]_, whereas in German they be outside, _"Das ist", rief er [...]_ etc. etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it is not directly programming related. Websites focusing on typographic questions might be better suited for this; I'd suggest a little googlin'.

Comment: @CBroe Should the linguistic standards of the targeted language to be applied then for such an example?

Comment: As a far as possible - of course! Is it not more aesthetically pleasing to your eye when you read a text in your mother tongue that uses punctuation "right", as opposed to it looking "weird"? CSS can help for example by automatically inserting the correct quote characters, respecting the language as indicated by a `lang` attribute, when the HTML properly respects the structure of the content as well (correct use of blockquote/quote/cite, etc.)

Comment: Look around the thematically relevant parts of the blogosphere/ twitter/ whathaveyou a bit - there's good articles on the combination of HTML & CSS and typography out there.

Comment: Duplicate of http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48540/in-a-sentence-ending-with-a-bold-or-italicised-word-does-the-period-need-to-be

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming or coding.